# gcc static lib linkage probolem

Tags: gcc, static, hyperlink

The libx.a has only one function x() which does nothing.
The liby.a has two functions, y() which does nothing and yx() which calls x() of libx.a.
Then, I have a main.c, in the funcion main() I calls y() of liby.a. When I do the link job, i must add libx.a, otherwise gcc will give an error saying: undefined refernce to 'x'. But I just use y() which has nothing to do with libx.a.
Is there anyway to make gcc ignore libx.a in my case? or in another words, can gcc only demand libx.a when libx.a is really needed?

The libpthread.a and libmysqlclient.a can do. I have a libm.a which uses libpthread and libmysqlclient. I wrote a main.c which only calls a empty function in libm.a, gcc will not request the libpthread.a and libmysqlclient.a when link. What's the differece between libpthread/libmysqlclient and my liby.a??

Answer (score 0):

> can gcc only demand libx.a when libx.a is really needed?

Yes. In fact, it only requires it when it is really needed. ***In this case, it's really needed.***

Comment: You could probably be a little more helpful with an explanation.

Comment: @MatthewHall what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: Consider that this is *static* linking. Why does the symbol reference from `main` to only the empty function `y` in `liby.a` force `libx.a` to be linked when it is only referenced from `liby.a`'s `yx`, which is unreachable from `y`, in `liby.a`?  Why is `libx.a` really needed, in theory or in practice?  The answer is that it *shouldn't be* with static linkage. Consider why it might be in practice, however.  Isn't a `.a` file merely an archive of object files, which define their own external symbols and symbol dependencies? If you make an assertion, try to support it.

Comment: Hey, just see my answer below.

Comment: @MatthewHall I believe because the compiler doesn't know by itself where to look for symbols. If you use a library that has dependencies and you're using static linkage, you will always have to specify those dependencies. If dynamic linkage is utilized, then it's not needed (since a dynamic library has already been linked against its dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another bbs a few minutes ago:
we should implement the y() and yx() in two seperated source files, for example, y() in y.c and yx() in yx.c. After doing this, gcc will not require libx.a!

I tested it, it is true!